# Show data with the same name only once

Tags: php, mysql

I need to show my billing history, so user can automatically submit by clicking submit. But instead of showing all transactions, I only have to show for each billing_name, so I should use `SELECT DISTINCT` right?

```
<?php
$query3 = "SELECT DISTINCT billing_name, billing_reference_num FROM billing_history";
$result3 = mysqli_query($link, $query3) or die(mysqli_error($link));
while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
    $billing_name = $row3['billing_name'];
    $billing_reference_num = $row3['billing_reference_num'];
    ?>
    <td><?php echo $billing_name ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $billing_reference_num ?></td>
    <?php
    $queryBill = "SELECT * FROM billing_history WHERE billing_name = '$billing_name'";
    $resultBill = mysqli_query($link, $queryBill) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    while ($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultBill)) {
        $billing_name_id = $row4['billing_name_id'];
        $account_id = $row4['account_id'];
        $account_number = $row4['account_number'];
    }
    ?>
    <td><input type="text" name="transaction_amount"/></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
    <input type="hidden" name="billing_name_id" value="<?php echo $billing_name_id ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="billing_name" value="<?php echo $billing_name ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="billing_reference_num" value="<?php echo $billing_reference_num ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="account_number" value="<?php echo $account_number ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="account_id" value="<?php echo $account_id ?>"/>
```

Comment: Two things that do not mix well: billing information and a sql vulnerability http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection. You seem to have little experience but are handling payment details. I strongly suggest to get an experienced developer doing this. (Don't get me wrong, learning is fine, messing with payment on a production server is not)

Comment: @samuel hey Im just doing a mock website